# Improving web hosting for high traffic website

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, iis-7, load-balancing

Our website is current running on a intel Xeon 2.3GHz that is about 5 or 6 years old with 8GB.

The website is current getting around 2,000 visitor per day. Running on windows 2008 R2 Web edition. The database is hosted on another server.

For time to time the website gets very slow, when there a lot of members at the same time. So I would like to know what is the best way to improve the website speed.

So far here is what I did.

1. All static files (images, css, video) are hosted on amazon S3 account.
2. We are current running the websites on a 6mbps T1 (4 T1s bounded)

I was planing on getting an instance on Amazon EC2. My question is can I setup a load balance from my server in the office and the Amazon EC2 instance? Since Amazon lets you start and stop the instance when you need, so I was planing only on using it when the website gets really busy.

Comment: Why not just put it altogether at amazon then? I don't know about amazon, but I know Azure supports the feature you are looking for.

Comment: How much is "a lot of members at the same time" ?  I run for example a machine with a single core Xeon E5410 with just 4 GB that easily handles 1500 simultaneous connections at times. And that machine also runs the MSSQL database server. Performance degradation is mostly due to bad code or bad database design.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon does not support what you are asking. EC2 only allows you to attach instances inside the amazon cloud to an amazon load balancer.

I think you would probably run into database issues if you had part of your infrastructure in the cloud. Its difficult to have a good connection from the cloud servers to your local database, so the cloud servers may end up being a good deal slower than your physical server.

You're better off going all cloud or all physical unless your database is in a location with a pipe directly to Amazon or Azure.